# Cambiar etiqueta "a" al cambiar color de fondo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y estoy haciendo algo simple que es cambiar el color de fondo y a la vez cambiar de color la fuente.

```js
function colorChanger(){
    if (document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#1F1F1F") {
        document.body.style.color = "#fff";
    }
}
```

```css
a {text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<p>
<a href="#" onclick="colorChanger()">Oscudo</a>
</p>

<h1>Cambiar fondo</h1>
```

Es muy simple, pero bueno, estoy aprendiendo y queria arrancar haciendo algo y me pasa que no logro hacer que el la etiqueta `a` cambia de color a blanco u otro color que se pueda ver.

Agradezco de antemano!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar un id para identificarlo y desde JS lo llamas mediante `document.getElementById` de la siguiente manera

```js
function colorChanger(){
    if (document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#1F1F1F") {
        document.body.style.color = "#fff";
        document.getElementById('enlace').style.color = "#fff";
    }
}
```

```css
a {text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<p>
<a id="enlace" href="#" onclick="colorChanger()">Oscudo</a>
</p>

<h1>Cambiar fondo</h1>
```

Comment: No habia pensado en agregar un id dentro de la etiqueta... muchas gracias Ruslan!

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo lo hagas de este modo:

- Para comparar es con doble o triple signo de igual
- Considera sacar del HTML el llamado directo de tu función, obteniendo dicha etiqueta por medio de su **id** y asignando un **`listener`** al evento **`click`** que posee; para que cuando ocurra este se ejecute la función que disparará los cambios de color
- Para obtener los valores de las reglas CSS, debes usar: **`getCumputedStyle`**
- Para obtener un valor CSS en specífico usa **`getPropertyValue`** la cual es una función que recibe como argumento entre comillas el nombre de la propiedad CSS que tratamos de leer para obtener su valor asignado
- Verificas si el valor del color existe, considerando que te lo va a mostrar como **`rgb(algun valor)`**

Quedando así

```html
    <style>
      body{
        background-color: black;
      }  
      h1{
        color: white;
      }
    a {text-decoration: none;}
    </style>
    <p>
    <a href="#" id="cambio">Oscuro</a>
    </p>
    
    <h1>Cambiar fondo</h1>
    <script>
      let cambio = document.getElementById("cambio")
      let fondo = document.querySelector("body")
      let titulo = document.querySelector("h1")
      let bodyEstilo = getComputedStyle(fondo)
      let bodyColor = bodyEstilo.getPropertyValue("background-color")
      
      cambio.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if(bodyColor === "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = " #FFFFFF"
          titulo.style.color = "#000000"
          cambio.style.color = "#000000"
        }
      })
    </script>
```

**Referencias en las cuales base la respuesta**

- [**`getComputedStyle`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)